# jquery autocomplete extraparams not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-autocomplete

**Js**

```
$('input.completeme').each(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({ url: '<?=base_url()?>patients/autocomplete',
                data: { 'term': this.term},
                extraParams: { format: this.element.attr('name') },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
});
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="patient_name" value="Patient name" class=completeme />
<input type="text" name="patient_id" value="ID" class=completeme />
```

It doesnt matter how hard i try it still send only "term" var to post page, and it doesnt send the extaparameter (i want to send the input name also to the php)

---

**What i want**

Autocomplete send 2 vars to my php file $term='the autocomplete search ' and $name="input name so my php can know what exact field its completing"

**What happens**

page run normal firebug show no error but when i check POST header it only send Term var

any help plz ??

Answer (score 0):

extraParams is jQuery autocomplete's option, but you're passing this option to another function — jQuery.ajax().

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input.completeme').each(function() {
    $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({ url: '<?=base_url()?>patients/autocomplete',
                data: { 'term': this.term,'name': this.element.attr('name') },
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data){
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
});
});
```

Finally works :D thank you all